# Strange signals on GPIO 14 & GPIO 4 when ribbon cable is attached to GPIO

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pigpio

I'm using **RP3B**.
I'm using **[piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html)**, as I don't have an oscilloscope available.

- After I boot my RP3B with nothing attached to the GPIO port, if I start [pigpiod](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) and piscope, I see all my GPIO with a constant signal level, as expected.
- After I boot my RP3B with a ribbon cable (IDE 40 pins) attached, and connected to a empty protoboard, if I start pigpiod and piscope, I can see some activity in [GPIOs 4](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin7_gpio4#) & [14 (TXD)](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin8_gpio14#). They look like clock/data running continously. It is not the same signal in both GPIOs. Unfortunately I don't have a print screen (and I'm cautious of connecting that cable again). But I can come with one if it looks safe.
- If I turn off the RPB3, detach the cable, and boot again, GPIOs return to normality (that is, no activity after boot).

Does anyone known what is happening? Thanks.

[image: Setup: RP3B, Ribbon cable detached, Protoboard]
<sup>*Setup: RP3B, Ribbon cable **detached**, Protoboard.*</sup>

[image: piscope after boot with no cable attach.]
<sup>*piscope after boot with no cable attach. No data/clock signals.*</sup>

Software versions:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /proc/device-tree/model 
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2

pi@raspberry:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberry 4.14.52-v7+ #1123 SMP Wed Jun 27 17:35:49 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberry:~ $ pigpiod -V
64
```

*piscope version: 0.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the GPIO are floating (not pulled-high or low) and that the ribbon cable wires are acting like an aerial.  It is quite possible that this will generate GPIO activity.

Try the following test.

`pigs pud 4 d`
`pigs pud 14 d`

That will set the internal pull-downs for GPIO 4 and 14. That might be enough to stop stray signals.

If it doesn't check the modes of those GPIO with the following command.

`pigs mg 4 mg 14`

It should report `0 0` indicating both GPIO are in INPUT mode.